# Where is the registry location for installed third-party software on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I just wanted to search for registry keys belonging to a third-party software I just installed on Windows 7, but I don't know where to look.

Are there defined spots in the registry where third-party software puts its keys?

Comment: For both locations mentioned below, also check under HKEY_CURRENT_USER for per-user non-admin installs.

Answer (score 4):

Typically,  3rd party software places their registry keys are put in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`.

Answer (score 3):

Also check in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE` (32-bit software on 64-bit machines)

Answer (score 0):

And the programs could be listed in `\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (Inside the both keys by @Keltari and @jtreser) which reveals many useful software installation and uninstall information.